# How to send long data through url?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to generate a graph using json data and rappid which is a visualization tool. iframe is basically an area where the html is loaded and the graph is shown using rappid.

```
 var graph=data;
    let iframeSrc = '../htmls/Flowcharts/RuleFlowchart.html?mode=upload&graph=' + graph
```

The data in var graph is:

```
{"cells": [{"type": "graph.Rule", "position": {"x": 100, "y": 100}, "size": {"width": "190", "height": "100"},
 "angle": "0", "id": "rr4001", "z": 4, "attrs": {"body": {"stroke": "#222138", "fill": "#feb663", "width": "50", "height": "30", "strokeDasharray": "0"}, 
"label": {"fontSize": "20", "fill": "#222138", "text": "crS1SetupSr", "fontFamily": "Roboto Condensed", "fontWeight": "Bold", "strokeWidth": "0", "refX": "50%", "refY": "50%"}, "root": {"dataTooltipPosition": "left", "dataTooltipPositionSelector": ".joint-stencil"}}, 
"flag": null, "RuleId": "crS1SetupSr", "latest": "True", "repoid": "00005e7366e4000000000004c4fb", 
"signum": null, "Comments": "", "expression1": "piS1_Setup_SuccRate", "expression2": 
"pmS1SigConnEstabAtt", "user_version": 1, "exp1operation": "NA", "exp1threshold": "<$AccS1SR$SRThr", .....

Its only the starting part. Like this data is present.
```

But when I am sending this through the iframe into another js where I will plot the graph, I am getting only this data. It is only sending till some certain point.

```
{"cells": [{"type": "ericsson.Rule", "position": {"x": 100, "y": 100}, "size": {"width": "190", "height": "100"},
 "angle": "0", "id": "rr4001", "z": 4, "attrs": {"body": {"stroke": "main
```

I need to send the entire data and not till that certain point. I want it in this format only. Is there any possible way I can do it?

Comment: Expect overlong Urls to be cut off. If the iframe contents origin with the same server, you can reference JS and DOM data from one iframe in the other. This will probably be the easiest way to provide the graph data to the plotter routine. Otherwise set a `localStorage` item to the graph data and have the plotting JS read it. The key could be a single parameter to the url you have the plotter iframe point to, to keep code changes  to a minimum. Example: ...

Comment: ...  `let myKey = 'key12345'; localStorage.setItem(myKey, graph); let iframeSrc = '../htmls/Flowcharts/RuleFlowchart.html?mode=upload&graph=' + myKey.`, in target frame: `let gr = localStorage.getItem(...);`.